# How can I output long datetime format which includes timzone with moment-timezone and react-intl?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, formatjs, react-intl

I have some client code which is using [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) to display currency, language, and date time values in a the user's defined language and region (culture/locale). In addition to these requirements I want to show the timezone abbreviation when using a long date and time format (ex. *8 February 2016, 15:02 GMT*).

To do this I've attempted to use the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) module which seems to do the right thing [in isolation](http://jsbin.com/paviruyire/edit?js,output). However I've found that in my application where *react-intl* is used the same line of code produces the correct data but in the wrong date-time format.

```
document.write(moment(Date()).tz("Europe/London").format('LLL z'));
```

**Expected:** 8 February 2016 20:57 GMT

**Actual:** February 8, 2016 9:04 PM GMT

My guess is that this has to do with the fact that I'm not loading in the moment *en-US* local directly since moment is being loaded in automatically for me as part of the *react-intl* library using the following type of code.

```
addLocaleData(en);

var intlData = {
    "locales": ["en-US", "en-GB"],
    "formats": {
        "date": {
            "short": {
                "day": "numeric",
                "month": "long",
                "year": "numeric"
            },
            "longdatetime": {
                "day": "numeric",
                "month": "long",
                "year": "numeric",
                "hour": "numeric", 
                "minute": "numeric"
            }
        },
        "time": {
            "hhmm": {
                "hour": "numeric",
                "minute": "numeric"
            }
        }
    }
};


const provider = <IntlProvider locale="en-GB" {...intlData}><MyApp /></IntlProvider>;
```

Related:

- https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/issues/19
- https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/49

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround I found that I can specifically set the **locale** for *moment-timezone* like so.

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

moment.locale('en-GB');
```